# sh file getting an error when enable multiple printers with CUPS

Tags: linux, command-line, printing, cups

I'm trying to use a script to enable multiple printers at once.

test.sh

```
sudo cupsenable hp1
sudo cupsenable hp2
```

command line

```
bash testh.sh
```

output

```
cupsenable: Operation failed: client-error-not-found
```

if my script has only one line it seems to work but if it has multiple lines then I get the error.

Not sure why I'm getting the error if you can run multiple commands in a sh file. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/cupsenable8.html) for `cupsenable` says you can list the printers in one line with single command e.g.

```
$ sudo cupsenable hp1 hp2
```

If you are still getting an error, be sure that you are typing the name of the printers correctly. You can list the printers with

```
$ sudo lpstat -v
```

Also check if you have the printer queues empty with

```
$ sudo lpstat -t
```